# How to compute the consistency of an estimator

Tags: statistical-inference

Can u help me?

consider a sample  $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ from the following density function

$$f_{\theta}(x)= \frac{1}{\theta}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\theta}x\right],\quad      x>0$$
where $\theta>0$ is an unknown parameter.

Show that the following estimator is weakly consistent for $\theta$:

$$T_n=\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\sum_{i}X_i-\frac{X_1}{n}$$

Comment: Here's a hint. Show that $T_n = \bar X + \frac{1}{n-1}\bar X - \frac{X_1}{n}$. Use the weak law of large numbers on $\bar X$, and show that the other two converge in probability to 0.

Comment: I’ll try, hoping I understand the hint

Answer (score 0):

$$
T_n = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum X_i - \frac{X_1}{n} = \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right) \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i - \frac{X_1}{n},
$$ 
Using the WLLN 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i \xrightarrow{p} EX = \theta,
$$
and $n/(n-1) \to 1$ and $X_1/n \to 0$, hence
$$
T_n \xrightarrow{p}1\times\theta+0=\theta.
$$

Comment: Thank you.. in this way I demonstrate that T is weakly consistent right?

Comment: Yes. Weakly consistent = converges in probability.